# JavaScript function not working on form submission

Tags: javascript, html, django

I've got an HTML form, and when it is submitted, I want a JavaScript function I have defined to run. However, no matter what, the function I've written is not recognised. Here is the HTML form:

```
<form id="compose-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        From: <input disabled class="form-control" value="{{ request.user.email }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        To: <input id="compose-recipients" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject">
    </div>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="compose-body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>
```

And then here is my JavaScript code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    
    // #compose is the id of the div the form #compose-form is in
    document.querySelector('#compose').addEventListener('click', compose_email);
    document.querySelector('#compose-form').addEventListener('submit', () => send_email(event));
});

function send_email(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Note this isn't the actual content of my function, but even this simple code doesn't work
    alert('Hello');
    return false;
}

function compose_email() {
    document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'block';

    // Note: this function does work completely.
    document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value = '';
    document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value = '';
    document.querySelector('#compose-body').value = '';
}
```

WHAT I'VE TRIED:

- I've moved the functions above the event listener in my JavaScript
- I've alternately removed both the `event.preventDefault();` and the `return false;`, removed both, kept both.
- I've tried defining the function separately, as I have it here, and doing the code as an anonymous function
- I've tried both `document.querySelector('#compose-form').addEventListener('submit', etc.)` and `document.querySelector('#compose.form').onsubmit = send_email(event)`.

I know the form doesn't have an `action=`; it isn't relevant. In all the searching I have done, this code should prevent the form from submitting, and perform the function, but for whatever reason it doesn't. When I click the submit button only a `?` is added to the URL, which I recognise as wanting queries, and that's handled elsewhere with my actual `send_email` function. I just want to know why my function appears to not be recognised and/or run.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `() => send_email(event)` (and the global `window.event` and a modified `this`) instead of just `send_email`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/Le61xkhz/

Comment: @Andreas it's just the way it appears in the code above - I tried using just `send_email` and it didn't work that way either. But I took a look at your JSFiddle and it appears to work, so the problem must be elsewhere for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks it has issue with `document.querySelector('#compose').addEventListener('click', compose_email);` Where is the element with id `compose`? It's not finding it.
I commented out that and it's firing the alert. Please check below

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        
        // #compose is the id of the div the form #compose-form is in
        //document.querySelector('#compose').addEventListener('click', compose_email);
        document.querySelector('#compose-form').addEventListener('submit', () => send_email(event));
    });

    function send_email(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Note this isn't the actual content of my function, but even this simple code doesn't work
        alert('Hello');
        return false;
    }

    function compose_email() {
        document.querySelector('#emails-view').style.display = 'none';
        document.querySelector('#compose-view').style.display = 'block';

        // Note: this function does work completely.
        document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value = '';
        document.querySelector('#compose-subject').value = '';
        document.querySelector('#compose-body').value = '';
    }
```

```html
<form id="compose-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        From: <input disabled class="form-control" value="{{ request.user.email }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        To: <input id="compose-recipients" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject">
    </div>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="compose-body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>
```